# Piping/Streaming all audio cross-platform to Android app

Tags: windows, linux, audio

**I wonder if there is really a way to create a cross-platform server/client program where you could simply send all audio output from a desktop PC to a homemade Android application which receives the pipe/stream of the sound?**

Windows seems to have no easy way to accomplish this without installing third-party or even commercial software (AirPlay is not an option).

The closest I've seen is people using PulseAudio+Icecast, but is this even possible on a Windows box as well? Many Linux users write about it, but it seems there is no real explanation of how to get it done on Windows.

Maybe someone knows a simple VideoLAN/VLC streaming setup (for the streaming/server part) that works like this (Would be too easy wouldn't it?) or another solution.

If it should be used on Windows it should be easy to deploy a complete package which I can put together w/ PulseAudio+Icecast if that really is possible.

Comment: So far I have yet to see an actual, answerable question here, at least no more than you have already stated. VLC is a cross-platform app that can stream over a network, write your app to make use of the stream it sends. Here is an example of streaming VLC over a network: http://www.wikihow.com/Use-VLC-Media-Player-to-Stream-Multimedia-to-Another-Computer

Comment: The guide you linked is about .avi and individual files, this is the whole audio output (incl. desktop sounds)

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be solved at [this arch thread](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1071943#p1071943). You basically streams your alsa output serving and transcoding it to `mp3` at the same time with ffmpg. To achieve so you need to:

1. Load a kernel module, virtual soundcard.
2. Tell Alsa to use this soundcard with a config file.
3. Tell ffmpg to listen to this soundcard with another config file.
4. Start the server.

Then you seem to be capable of playing it simply by connecting to `http://your.computer.ip:8090/stream.mp3`. Probably works with your browser, but you can try some streaming players such as VLC or MXPlayer on your Android.

Comment: Hi and welcome to superuser. To prevent link degradation we ask that posts as answers contain the answer itself (in case the link dies). Whilst this doesn't mean to copy verbatim from the linked source, please consider including some additional information so that someone reading your answer on this site might be able to understand and come to the same conclusion as yourself.

Comment: I've been indenting code by hand for almost ten minutes (four spaces and the following will be code) but doesn't seem to work. `code block` button doesn't work either. It allwais worked at stackoverflow. I don't understand, and I'm not posting code thats not formated.
I think my answer is enough to understand what follows the link.